# wp-content/uploads returns a 404

Tags: uploads

I was doing some speed tests on my site recently and I noticed that my wp-content/uploads folder takes a long time to connect and then gives a 404 error. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: What do you mean that it returns a 404? Are you able to view any of your uploads? And what are the settings in your Settings > Media panel set to?

Answer (score 1):

That folder shouldn't be something that you're directly linking to anyway, in 99% of cases. It should have a 501 Not Authorized via .htaccess, or just a blank index.php page within it.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I believe that somehow the index.php in the folder was deleted recently. When I added it again the 404 stopped. Pingdom is still showing that it takes a long time (3.2 secs) to connect to that folder though and several of the images on my home page. I have never had a problem with it taking that long to load before.